# Express.js shutdown hook

Tags: node.js, express

In Express.js, is there someway of setting a callback function to be executed when the application shuts down?

Comment: The below answers are not useful in every day activity, you're looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14031763/doing-a-cleanup-action-just-before-node-js-exits) - process.on('SIGINT', () => { ...})

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You could use the node.js [core process 'exit' event](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#event_exit_) like so:

```js
process.on('exit', function() {
  // Add shutdown logic here.
});
```

Of course, the main event loop will stop running after the exit function returns so you can't schedule any timers or callbacks from within that function (e.g. any I/O must be synchronous).

Comment: can I use `async function()` there ?

Comment: @HendyIrawan yes you can use `async`

Comment: @emc it's false! You can't use async code in 'exit' handler. See here: https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_exit
"Listener functions must only perform synchronous operations".
The best alternative I found so far to handle exit for any possible reason is handling each signal event, as described in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40574758/2879716

Answer (score 11):

There is [process.on('exit', callback)](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.6.5/api/process.html#event_exit_):

```
process.on('exit', function () {
  console.log('About to exit.');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The express team recommends the [terminus](https://github.com/godaddy/terminus) package:

https://expressjs.com/en/advanced/healthcheck-graceful-shutdown.html

Answer (score 1):

If you need to access something in the current scope, you can `bind()` like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14032965/1410035 but you might want to bind `this`.

> ```
> function exitHandler(options, err) {
>     if (options.cleanup) console.log('clean');
>     if (err) console.log(err.stack);
>     if (options.exit) process.exit();
> }
>
> process.on('exit', exitHandler.bind(null,{cleanup:true}));
> ```

Comment: Or just use an arrow function. Its scope is wherever it's declared. `const exitHandler = (options, err) => {...}`