# Node.js and mysql Callback : query in query callback

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, node-mysql

All I want to do is insert some data if my database doesn't have that, so I put Insert SQL into my callback function of my Select SQL, but I got error like this:

> { [Error: Cannot enqueue Query after invoking quit.] code: 'PROTOCOL_ENQUEUE_AFTER_QUIT', fatal: false }

my code snippet is here:

```
db.query('SELECT count(*) as Resultcount FROM tablename WHERE email = ? and password = ?', [post.email, post.password], function(error, result){
    if (result[0].Resultcount == 0){
        var query2 = db.query('INSERT INTO tablename SET ?', [post], function(err, result) {
            if(err){
              console.log(err);
           }
             console.log(result);
          });
    }
    else{
        console.log('have data already');
    }
});
```

Could someone give me some advice? 
Thanks

----update----

actually, the callback function of select SQL is not an anonymous function, my code snippet about db.end() is like this:

```
var QueryResults = new queryResultFuntion(Back_results);

    db.query('SELECT count(*) as Resultcount FROM tablename WHERE email = ? and password = ?', [post.email, post.password], QueryResults.queryResult );


    db.end();
```

Comment: Are you closing your DB connection somewhere after this code?

Comment: yes, when I finish db.query('select ...'), I called db.end();

Comment: That means that by the time your INSERT query runs, the connection will be closed. Please add that code to your question and I'll make an answer.

Comment: Also, when do you create the connection?

Comment: my connection is create when the exports function be called

Comment: I move my db.end() to my callback function of Insert SQL, and it works!
It seems like I just didn't full understand how asynchronous works...

but thank you anyway!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You `db.end()` call will queue the connection to close once the `SELECT` has completed, so when you attempt to do the inner `INSERT` query, the database connection will have been closed, hence the error PROTOCOL_ENQUEUE_AFTER_QUIT, as you are attempting to queue a new command after the connection is closed.

Depending on how you are creating the connection, you should either move your `db.end()` call inside the callbacks, or not have a `db.end()` call at all if the connection is opened on program start.

Comment: Not doing `db.end()` at all results in having to terminate my script (which I'm starting on the command line with the `node` command) with Ctrl-C.  But this did get rid of `PROTOCOL_ENQUEUE_AFTER_QUIT`

Comment: @Lori Correct, that's why I prefaced it with `Depending on how you are creating the connection`. If you are writing a node server for instance, you'd only open the connection once, and there is no expectation that the server would every exit anyway. If you are writing a script, you'd want to end the connection once all of the operations in your script have completed.

Comment: for me, I placed `connection.end()` or `db.end()` (in your case), outside of the result callback.  As a result, it was ending the connection even before the callback has returned.  Therefore the error is coming.  So I just made sure its inside the `connection.query or db.query` block.   `connection.query(sql, (err,result)=> {
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log(result)
    connection.end();
  })`