# ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS with Node and Mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, npm

I know three ways to solve this problem.

1. With a stored procedure.
2. Ignoring the error and continue.
3. Working an algorithm in backend

I would resolve with Node in my backend. So I did this.

```js
let exist = false
connection.query(`
     SELECT IF(count(*) = 1, 'Exist','Not Exist') AS result
     FROM information_schema.columns
     WHERE table_schema = 'database'
       AND table_name = 'table_name'
       AND column_name = '${columnName}';
    `,
    (error, results, fields) => {
       if (error) throw error
       else if (results[0].result === 'Exist') {
         exist = true
       }
     }
)
if (!exist) {
   connection.query(`
      ALTER TABLE ofertas
      ADD COLUMN ${columnName} VARCHAR(255);
      `,
      (error, result, fields) => {
        if (error) throw error
      }
  )
}
```

This code not work. I belive the problem is async because *exist* always is true.
I use [mysql module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql)

Comment: What if you run the alter table statement as a callback to the check?

Comment: @mmenschig If i do that get Error: Cannot enqueue Query after invoking quit. code: 'PROTOCOL_ENQUEUE_AFTER_QUIT

Comment: Are you calling `db.end()` anywhere in your code? try calling it at the end of your callback. Appears related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16134378/node-js-and-mysql-callback-query-in-query-callback