# json post method format

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, express

I got following format when i send post request from postman.

```
{
   ID:"66",
   Blod:"test",
   Allergic:"no",
   Chronic:"no"
}
```

But i got this format when i send post request using react app post method.

```
[Object: null prototype] 
{
 '{
 "ID":"123456789",
 "Blod":"22334445",
 "Allergic":"6677788",
 "Chronic":"3445566"}': ''
}
```

please help me how can I got the same format of postman to insert data correctly.

this is my method from react app uisng axios module :

```
submithandler=(e)=>{
      e.preventDefault();
     axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api/addsickers',
     JSON.stringify({
         ID:'123456789',
         Blod:'22334445',
         Allergic:'6677788',
         Chronic:'3445566'
        }),

     )
       .then(response=>{
           alert(response);
       })
       .catch(err=>{
           alert("catch"+err);
       });
  }
```

I use parsing on api

```
app.use(bodyparser.json());
// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended: false });
// parse the raw data
app.use(bodyparser.raw());
// parse text
app.use(bodyparser.text());
```

Comment: Can you mention your node.js post method also?

Comment: it contain just `router.post('/',(req,res)=>{console.log(req.body)})` I have commented other code cause when posting from react app it insert undefined values , and working fine when using postaman.

Comment: You don't have to stringify , you can directly send javascript object/json with axios

Comment: as i understand..Your postman request work just fine and react post request behave different? is that the problem?

Comment: yes exactly bro.

Comment: Your react request behavior is correct. I think the issue you are facing now is that you cant process the incoming react request from node.js. right?

Comment: not exactly , the problem is the format of the json , if I use postman I got correct format , for example I can get the value of ID by writing `req.body.ID` but in second format that I got from react app if I write `req.body.ID` it returns undefined value .

Comment: if i removed `JSON.stringfy` i got this error from catch **Error: Network Error**

Comment: can you mention full stack trace error if we remove `JSON.stringfy` ??

Comment: the full error I got from catch is just "Error: Network Error"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this by using fetch method like the following :

```
senddata(event){
      event.preventDefault();
   //if(!this.formvalidation())
    //{
    try{
    fetch('https://localhost:8000/api/addsickers/',{
     method:'post',
     mode:'no-cors',
     headers:{
         'Accept':'application/json',
         'Content-type': 'application/json'
     },
     body:JSON.stringify({
            ID:this.state.code,
             Blod:this.state.blod,
             Allergic:this.state.allergic+" - "+this.state.allergicdescription,
             Chronic:this.state.chronic+" - "+this.state.chronic_description
     })
    });
    alert("data goes")
    }catch(e){
        alert(e)
    }
    //}
}
```

and in api I did :

```
let request = JSON.parse(req.body)
console.log(request);
```

and I got the same forma of postman tool that let me to call attributes correctly for insert , for example : ***request.ID*** return the correct value.

thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the postman request configuration
settings as follows.

[image]

If the problem you are facing now is that **how to process incoming react request**, the 
following code snippet will helps you.

```
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    let request = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body));
    console.log(request.ID);
});
```

Comment: thanks for reply , this was the output of json `{
  '{"ID":"123456789","Blod":"22334445","Allergic":"6677788","Chronic":"3445566"}': ''
}`  and the resulte of  `console.log(request.ID);`  was   `undefined`

Comment: @AzizMobarak this the valid json object, with one field, where `{"ID":"123456789","Blod":"22334445","Allergic":"6677788","Chronic":"3445566"}` is a key, an empty string is a value.

Comment: yes this is true , and I don't know why all the object consedred as one key that has an empty value.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to use 'JSON.stringify' , like this:

```
submithandler=(e)=>{
      e.preventDefault();
     axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api/addsickers',
     {
         ID:'123456789',
         Blod:'22334445',
         Allergic:'6677788',
         Chronic:'3445566'
     },

     )
       .then(response=>{
           alert(response);
       })
       .catch(err=>{
           alert("catch"+err);
       });
  }
```

Comment: thank you for reply , I have tried it before and it lanch the catch error and say "Error: Network Error"

Comment: @AzizMobarak however in the documentation for axios, they do it like in the answer, possibly need to investigate the server configuration

Comment: I m using loclal host , I will try it online too , and I will see if something has changed

Answer (score 0):

In your code you don't need this code:

```
// parse the raw data
app.use(bodyparser.raw());
// parse text
app.use(bodyparser.text());
```

As the documentation states:

**[bodyparser.raw()](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser#bodyparserrawoptions)** Returns middleware that parses all bodies as a Buffer and only looks at requests where the Content-Type header matches the type option.

And

**bodyParser.text()** Returns middleware that parses all bodies as a string and only looks at requests where the Content-Type header matches the type option. This parser supports automatic inflation of gzip and deflate encodings.

You have to change that line from:

```
 bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended: false });
```

to:

```
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended: false });
```

Comment: thanks I agree , the post method still send the same json forma tha does not easy to read data from it , the data that insert into api like that   `[Object: null prototype] {
  '{"ID":"123456789","Blod":"22334445","Allergic":"6677788","Chronic":"3445566"}': ''`  ,, and I m looking to get the same data when using post man like `{ID:'123456789' ....}` , for example the second one is easy to return ID by typing `req.body.ID` but the first format will return undefined cause it not clear

Comment: @AzizMobarak Possibly your data badly parsed on the server side

Comment: I will check about that and see if result changed