# Trigger Event On Server Shutdown (NodeJS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, session

As we all know, when you update a nodejs file and upload it to your server, it needs a restart to be applied -- but if you're using something like `nodemon` where it automatically restarts your server, your clients that are logged in would need to refresh the screen.

So I was wondering, is there a way I could trigger a "logout" when my server goes down/is restarted so that at the minimum it just refreshes the clients so they know what's happened?

As it stands they'll broadcast undefined errors because theyre session has been lost?

I tried to validate using a function I have called `authenticate`

```
function authenticate(req,res,next) {
    if (!req.session.loggedIn) {
        fs.readFile('./html/login.html', "utf8", function(err, html) {
            res.send(html);
        });
    } else next();
}
```

and here's how I call the function:

```
app.io.route('move', authenticate, function(req) {
```

But my server crashes because the parameters are undefined at that point.

Basically think of it like an `onbeforeunload` event but instead of the browser, the server.

Comment: izuriel I am using socket.io, it's embedded in express.io. I just don't know how to detect a restart

Comment: I've removed my comments and replaced them with an answer to expand on what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

The approach I would take is have something like Socket.IO notify all connected clients that your server is performing a restart, this restart notice, once received, would cause the client to disconnect the socket and poll for the server to come back up. Once it's back up, you can do a hard or soft refresh.

```
Server                   Server                            
SIGINT/Exit received --> io.broadcast("server:restart") --

  Client                        Client
-> receive "server:restart" --> disconnect socket, poll for server back up --

  Client
-> load refreshed data
```

You can capture some signal events like shown here and based on some information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14031763/doing-a-cleanup-action-just-before-node-js-exits) you can use the "exit" event.

```
process.on("exit", function() {
  app.io.sockets.emit("server:shutdown");
});
```

This will only work if the emit process is syncrhonous (and it looks like it may be). That means you can't get a callback you can only broadcast the message and let the client do the rest.

If you want to "hard refresh" you can poll a "heartbeat" route that just returns if the server is good (and running, obviously) and then do a `location.reload()` call. For a soft refresh, ping a route that returns new page contents and then page swap (`$("body").html(response)`).

Comment: This does not do anything when `nodemon` restarts the server

Comment: You are correct, it appears that nodemon sends a SIGKILL which is not an event you can capture.

Comment: Dang, I was scared of that. Thank you though, I appreciate your help. Where did you find that by the way? I'd love to read that

Comment: I tested it locally with a small script. The part about Nodemon that is, I tried listening for `"exit"`, `"SIGTERM"` and `"SIGKILL"` (which errored). Of course, from Node.js docs "SIGKILL cannot have a listener installed, it will unconditionally terminate node on all platforms."