# close server on node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cron

I use `node.js` to load dynamic crontab to to operation system
and I want to add close function that when I close the `node.js` server it call this function and remove all the crontabs

Code:

```
var server = app.listen(8080, function() {
  loadCronTab("*/1 * * * * date");
  console.log('Server running...');
});


server.on('close', function () {
  closeCronTab();
  console.log("Closed");
  redis.quit();
});
```

The remove function is:

```
function closeCronTab()
{
    require('crontab').load(function(err, crontab) {
      if (err) {
        return console.error(err);
      }
      var command = 'ls -l';
      crontab.remove({command:command});
      crontab.save(function(err, crontab) {

      });
    });
}
```

I have use var express with my `node.js` it can help?

I don't know how to write the close function syntax.. =(

I try

```
var server = app.listen(8080, function() {
  console.log('Server running...');
});

server.close(function(){
  closeCronTab();
  console.log("Closed");
});
```

But it runs the server and closes it after a second..

Comment: what do you mean by "var express with my node.js"?

Comment: Express module on node.js

Answer (score 0):

Check [this answer about process exiting events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14031763/doing-a-cleanup-action-just-before-node-js-exits), but note that it's not guaranteed. Power loss, SIGKILL (kill -9), segfault, and other hard exits can't be handled.