# Restore project on gulp error

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I use gulp to change files of my project.

```
gulp.task('task1', function(){
    // change file1
});

gulp.task('task2', function(){
    // change file2
});
```

And if one of the tasks fails (due to error), I need to restore whole project.

So im planning to make a backup, and on `err` event of gulp, copy backup files to my project.

```
gulp.on('err', function(err){
    // restore
});
```

But if someone press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> while files are copied, project would not be fully restored. What are the common techniques of restoring?

Comment: Interesting, I haven't seen this workflow ("changing/restoring" files), normally I'd see Gulp used for generating processed files out of some source files. Can you give some more context?

Comment: @Kos, I update my project to newer version. So project of version 1 got one file structure and project with version 2 other. And I use gulp to automate update process (its global module that uses gulp internally).

Answer (score 0):

Gulp is actually a node process. Node has a variety of [events you can bind to](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html). In your case, you will probably want to register your handler to: exit, SIGINT and uncaughtException.

For examples see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14031763/doing-a-cleanup-action-just-before-node-js-exits).

--- edit ---

Following Atrem's comment, it seems like only synch ops will hold (and the documentation state it). To overcome this you might want to spawn a new process to do the shutdown actions you need to do.

Comment: but `Ctrl` + `C` doesn't wait for files to copy, it stops the process immediately.

Comment: It does if you use 'SIGINT'.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ot9f9rr7/3/, Ive tested SIGINT, and it doesn't log message, but it writes file, but not much files