# Should i make static list per model for server-client application?

Tags: java, javafx

I am building a server-client business application using javaFx.
My issue is, should i use static list to store data retrieved from server for each model as they are referred on different view.
The list may contain thousand's of objects as the data grows.
I think the list may take up a lot of memory on the other hand to query server for each event may use resources on server.

Server application : nodejs
Server database : mysql
information exchange : RESTful api
client application : javaFx

Comment: Why isn't the data in a database?

Comment: Data is stored in MySql database on server, server is running nodejs application to serve the data

Comment: Use [Pagination on the JavaFX client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15349185/javafx-tableview-paginator) and a [Rest based paginator on the server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35694504/pagination-in-nodejs-with-mysql).  I am unfamiliar with node.js, so I won't provide any further input here on how to achieve this.  This is a non-trivial problem and may be closed as too broad for a StackOverflow question.  [DataFX](http://www.javafxdata.org) may help.

Answer (score 0):

Use file to store data and list for maintaining those files.

Comment: could you please share some example or blog or something on implementation