# Sending http request on node process exit

Tags: node.js, http, process, request, exit

I have written sample node application to handle error data such as database connection error, port conflict error, process uncaught exception. When error occurrs an http request is made to process the error. In such case when node process exist abnormally, I am able to handle exist in `process.on('exit')` function but I am not able to send http request, the process is exiting quickly.

Can any one suggest how to send http request and get the response on Node.js before process exit. Below is the sample code for sending http request on process exists

```
var http = require('http');
var errorData=null;
var sendErrorReport = function(data,callback){
    var options = {
        host : connection.host,
        path : "/api/errorReport",
        port : connection.port,
        method : 'POST',
        timeout: connection.timeInterval,
        headers:{
            'Content-Type':'application/json',
            'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(data)}
    }
    var request =  http.request(options,function(response){
        callback(response);
    });
    request.on('error',function(err){
        console.log("On Error");
        callback(err);
    });
    request.on('timeout', function(err){console.log("On Timeout");
        callback(err);});
    request.write(data);
    request.end();
}
process.on('uncaughtException', function ( err ) {
    errorData = err;
});
process.on('exit',function(code){
    sendErrorReport(errorData,function(err,res){
        console.log(res);
    });

})
```

Comment: If you handle `SIGINT` or `uncaughtException` events, you can call `process.exit` in the callback of the request. It should hang until you call that `.exit()` function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [doing a cleanup action just before node.js exits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14031763/doing-a-cleanup-action-just-before-node-js-exits)

Comment: In some cases I need to handle the process exit when uncaught exception is not  thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Hit on same problem, 
according to the doc https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_exit

"Event: 'exit' Listener functions must only perform synchronous operations." make it hard to send request to other system.

A possible workaround method is to to execute another script/cmd, eg.

```
import exec from 'child_process'

mocha.run(failures => {
  process.on('exit', () => {
    exec.execSync(some cmd, function (error, stderr) {
      if (error) {
        throw (error);
      }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `process.on('exit', [fn])` you cannot do any asynchronous action as stated in the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_exit). However, this is an anti-pattern also discovered in many libraries.

You need to rely on `process.on('uncaughtException', [fn])` or any signal handlers like `SIGTERM`.