# Kill spawned child processes

Tags: node.js, child-process, worker

So I have spawned one child process that I keep alive as long as the main process is alive. Since I use it very often I see no reason to kill it every few seconds.

How can I be sure to close the child process upon exiting the main one whether it crashed or not since if I don't it will become orphan. Also if I happen to get an orphan child what should I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [doing a cleanup action just before node.js exits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14031763/doing-a-cleanup-action-just-before-node-js-exits)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [process on exit](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_exit) event:

```
process.on('exit', (code) => {
  // kill all workers
});
```

EDIT: I found more complex solution: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14032965/7526159

Comment: That doesn't guarantee it will close upon any exit code.

Comment: Since the workers will be draining resources its important to know I can kill them all upon exiting, so using a scenario where it might not kill them, is not the best case. Also I should mention I use a fork to spawn the childs, so am not 100% sure the parent doesn't kill them before existing, but upon searching thats what I came to understand.

Comment: Ok. In child process we can listen on process.on('disconnect') event, and kill current process. 
https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_disconnect
https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_event_disconnect