# How to get event when system is about to go to sleep

Tags: javascript, node.js, process

Is it possible to get notified when the system is about to change its power state to sleep?

Something like

```
process.on('sleep', () => foo())
```

When going to sleep, the process does not get killed or exit, so answers from
[doing a cleanup action just before node.js exits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14031763/doing-a-cleanup-action-just-before-node-js-exits) do not suffer.

Answer (score -1):

Your programm receive informations from your Operating System in linux from  [signals](https://www.linuxtricks.fr/wiki/signaux-unix-unix-signals). I guess the signal you are looking for is from the following list:

[image]

---

To handle signals in node.js [here](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_signal_events) is how you do it :

```
// Begin reading from stdin so the process does not exit.
process.stdin.resume();

process.on('SIGINT', () => {
  console.log('Received SIGINT. Press Control-D to exit.');
});

// Using a single function to handle multiple signals
function handle(signal) {
  console.log(`Received ${signal}`);
}

process.on('SIGINT', handle);
process.on('SIGTERM', handle);
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, none of these events get fired when the power state changes. Not even SIGPWR.