# Node program always exits before tasks in process.on('SIGINT') can finish

Tags: node.js

I am trying to make my Node program exit gracefully on `Ctrl+C`, but the tasks never finish before the program exits.

index.js:

```
require('dotenv').config()
const log = require('./middleware/log')
const error = require('./middleware/error')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')
const cleanup = require('./middleware/cleanup');

(async () => {

  // handle Ctrl+C
  process.on('SIGINT', () => {
    cleanup(browser) // this never finishes before the program ends
    process.exit(2)
  })

  // log program exit
  process.on('exit', (code) => {
    if (code === 2) {
      log('Program exited manually.')
    } else if (code === 1) {
      log('Program crashed.')
    } else {
      log('Program exited.')
    }
    cleanup(browser) // I've tried putting it here too, but it still doesn't finish before the program ends
    process.exit(code)
  })

  await mongoose.connect(
    'mongodb://' + process.env.MONGO_USER_DEV + ':' + process.env.MONGO_PW_DEV + '@' + process.env.MONGO_IP_DEV + ':' + process.env.MONGO_PORT_DEV + '/' + process.env.MONGO_DB_DEV,
    {
      useNewUrlParser: true
    }
  )

  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true })
  page = await browser.newPage()

  // do stuff

  cleanup(browser)

})().catch(async (err) => {
  cleanup(browser)
  error(err)
})
```

cleanup.js:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

module.exports = (browser) => {
  mongoose.disconnect()
    .then(res => {
      browser.close()
        .then(res => {
          return
        })
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

normally the doc states that you shouldnt perform async tasks in cleanup... however you can find a hack in this long duplicate post .   [doing a cleanup action just before node.js exits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14031763/doing-a-cleanup-action-just-before-node-js-exits).  hope it helps.

Comment: Okay but am I not calling a synchronous function?

Comment: ok just the naming is weird.   anyway check the link.  exactly the same issues.

Comment: It looks like they're doing the same thing I am.