# How can I listen "stop" event in npm?

Tags: node.js

I want to listen event "stop" or something else.

And when this event get triggered I want to run some other code.

Comment: Please tell me what are you need ??

Comment: I think he means listening for exit and cmd+c https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14031763/doing-a-cleanup-action-just-before-node-js-exits