# EADDRINUSE error: How do you run nodemon with express so it does not listen to a port that is already in use?

Tags: express, slack-api, nodemon

I am working on a slack bot tutorial that runs express server and runs concurrently, nodemon, and ngrok.

The problem I am running into is:

> Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::5000

I think the error happens because nodemon re-runs express when an update happens. `index.js`:

```
const server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000, () => {
  console.log('Express server listening on port %d in %s mode', server.address().port, app.settings.env);
});
```

I've gone down several rabbit holes that include parent and child 'processes' (https://dev.to/kyrelldixon/how-to-setup-an-express-js-server-in-node-js-56hp)

And / or it looks like this may be some kind of bug due to an update (https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/1025)

I have even thought about adding some kind of callback on `.listen` so app checks for whether or not a port is running (http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#app.listen_path_callback)

But ultimately, not sure how to figure out the issue. Can anyone provide some guidance?

my setup:

```
npm -v
1.5.0
node -v
v10.16.3
nodemon -v
v2.0.2
express -v
v4.16.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

adding something like

```
process.on(‘SIGINT’, () => { console.log(“exiting…“); process.exit(); });

process.on(‘exit’, () => { console.log(“exiting…“); process.exit(); });
```

in your main js file should catch these situations and allow for you to make sure the process exits properly. You could expand to call a function to additional clean up as well

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14031763/doing-a-cleanup-action-just-before-node-js-exits the accepted answer here might get you on track! good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This happens when there is a service already running and acquiring that port.

Sometimes when you exit the application with `Ctrl-c` the process doesn't gets kill completely and keeps running in the background.

You can check which process is acquiring your port using this command

```sh
    netstat -tulnp | grep '<port number>'
```

[image]

Will look something like this ^^

And then kill that process with the process id provided by the above command.

> 57997 in my case

You can also check if there is any process running already in the background using `ps` command.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I can get out of this error when I kill processes individually, but it looks like I have to do this every time nodemon runs the app. Is there a way to handle this programmatically so I don't evfer need to check processes?

Comment: This [**nodemon** issue](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/1109) may be the problem you are facing.
One of the solution which solved the problem was updating to gitbash `2.16` as said [here](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/1109#issuecomment-370981817) Can you try this?

Comment: Ah bummer `3.2.57(1)-release`