# How to stop Node API cluster server properly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm just learning to use clusters in my Koa + TypeScript API. I found a blog post and took references from it.

```
// server.ts

import {app} from './app' // Koa

export function server() {
  const http = app.listen(8000, async () => {
    console.info(`Listening at 8000`)
  })
  return http
}
```

```
// main.ts

async function main() {
  try {
    // Create or migrate
    await knex.migrate.latest()
    return server()
  } catch (err) {
    logger.error('Failed to start: ', err.stack)
    process.exit(1)
  }
}

// Clustering
const numCPUs = cpus().length

if (cluster.isMaster) {
  logger.info(`${numCPUs} CPUs available`)
  for (let i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
    cluster.fork()
  }

  cluster.on('online', worker => {
    logger.info(`Worker ${worker.process.pid} is online`)
  })

  cluster.on('disconnect', worker => {
    logger.error(`${worker.process.pid} disconnect!`)
    cluster.fork()
  })

  /** I do not think I need this block, right?
   *
  cluster.on('exit', (worker, code, signal) => {
    logger.info(
      `Worker ${worker.process.pid} died with code: ${code} and signal: ${signal}`,
    )
    logger.info('Starting a new worker...')
    cluster.fork()
  })
   */
} else {
  main()
}
```

And I have this graceful shutdown function:

```
// Graceful shutdown
async function shutdown() {
  try {
    await knex.destroy().then(() => {
      logger.warn('Destroyed Knex pool')
    })
    // Make sure we close down within 30 seconds
    const killtimer = setTimeout(() => {
      process.exit(1)
    }, 30000)
    // But don't keep the process open just for that!
    killtimer.unref()
    server().close(() => {
      logger.warn('Closed server')
      process.exit()
    })
    // Let the maste know w're dead.
    // return cluster.worker.disconnect()
  } catch (e) {
    logger.error(`Error during disconnection: ${e.stack}`)
    process.exit(1)
  }
}

function awaitHardStop() {
  const timeout = SHUTDOWN_TIMEOUT ? +SHUTDOWN_TIMEOUT : 1000 * 30
  return setTimeout(() => {
    logger.error(`Process did not terminate within ${timeout}ms. Stopping now!`)
    process.nextTick(process.exit(1))
  }, timeout)
}

// Catch unhandling unexpected exceptions
process.on('uncaughtException', e => {
  logger.error(`Uncaught exception: ${e.message}`)
  process.nextTick(process.exit(1))
})

// Catch unhandling rejected promises
process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason, promise) => {
  logger.error(`Unhandled rejection at ${promise}, reason: ${reason}`)
  process.nextTick(process.exit(1))
})

process.on('SIGINT', async () => {
  logger.warn(`[ SIGNAL ] - SIGINT`)
  const timer = awaitHardStop()
  await shutdown()
  clearTimeout(timer)
})

process.on('SIGTERM', async () => {
  logger.warn(`[ SIGNAL ] - SIGTERM`)
  const timer = awaitHardStop()
  await shutdown()
  clearTimeout(timer)
})

process.on('SIGUSR2', async () => {
  logger.warn(`[ SIGNAL ] - SIGUSR2`)
  const timer = awaitHardStop()
  await shutdown()
  clearTimeout(timer)
})
```

Issue is I got this when I stop with `Ctrl+c`:

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::8000
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1313:16)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1361:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1447:7)
    at Application.listen (/home/usr/workspace/koa-ts/app/node_modules/koa/lib/application.js:82:19)
    at Object.server (/home/usr/workspace/koa-ts/app/src/core/server.ts:7:20)
    at /home/usr/workspace/koa-ts/app/src/main.ts:71:5
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (/home/usr/workspace/koa-ts/app/src/main.ts:24:58)
{"level":50,"time":1597173528053,"pid":284878,"hostname":"usr-PC","msg":"Uncaught exception: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::8000"}
```

So I tried adding this line in `main.ts` just below `server().close()`:

```
    ...
    // Let the maste know w're dead.
    return cluster.worker.disconnect()
    ...
```

Then I got this when `Ctrl+c`:

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::8000
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1313:16)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1361:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1447:7)
    at Application.listen (/home/usr/workspace/koa-ts/app/node_modules/koa/lib/application.js:82:19)
    at Object.server (/home/usr/workspace/koa-ts/app/src/core/server.ts:7:20)
    at /home/usr/workspace/koa-ts/app/src/main.ts:71:5
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (/home/usr/workspace/koa-ts/app/src/main.ts:24:58)
{"level":50,"time":1597173528053,"pid":284878,"hostname":"usr-PC","msg":"Uncaught exception: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::8000"}
{"level":50,"time":1597173554364,"pid":285843,"hostname":"usr-PC","msg":"Error during disconnection: TypeError: Cannot read property 'disconnect' of undefined\n    at /home/usr/workspace/koa-ts/app/src/main.ts:76:27\n    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)\n    at fulfilled (/home/usr/workspace/koa-ts/app/src/main.ts:24:58)"}
{"level":50,"time":1597173554364,"pid":285843,"hostname":"usr-PC","msg":"Error during disconnection: TypeError: Cannot read property 'disconnect' of undefined\n    at /home/usr/workspace/koa-ts/app/src/main.ts:76:27\n    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)\n    at fulfilled (/home/usr/workspace/koa-ts/app/src/main.ts:24:58)"}
llsi/app/src/main.ts:24:58)"}
{"level":50,"time":1597173997176,"pid":287724,"hostname":"usr-PC","msg":"Error during disconnection: TypeError: Cannot read property 'disconnect' of undefined\n    at /home/usr/workspace/koa-ts/app/src/main.ts:76:27\n    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)\n    at fulfilled (/home/usr/workspace/koa-ts/app/src/main.ts:24:58)"}
```

Is it normal or am I doing something wrong here?

I am using Node (v12.18.3).

Ref: http://bisaga.com/blog/programming/create-a-node-cluster-with-koa-and-typescript/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Doing a cleanup action just before Node.js exits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14031763/doing-a-cleanup-action-just-before-node-js-exits)

Check out what was suggested here. I was also looking for a way to do cleanup on any form of process termination... You should basically only do the termination if cleanup is true. Also I suggest you look into a process manager. For example check out PM2, it allows you to start your application in a cluster easily and manages the different worker processes for you!

Comment: It literally kills. Thank you so much! One more question though, can I completely replace my boatload Graceful-Shutdown function with it? For PM2, I was using it before. But now I'm with Docker and I saw people don't recommend running PM2 inside Docker. Would you use PM2 inside Docker?

Comment: Sorry it's hard to say... never encountered the issue with pm2 and docker. But perhaps there are other alternatives? As to the question if you can replace it... during cleanup you should be able to call anything that you need to well cleanup. It will be a bit hard to say what can be removed exactly. Experiment?

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try it out. :)

Comment: No problem! Sorry I can't help more