# Sveltekit How do I run code when server exits

Tags: database, exit, sveltekit

How do I run code when my Sveltekit application is exiting?

I have a hooks.server.ts file that initializes a DB connection when the app starts. If my server shuts off, how do I close the connection?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think there is such hook available yet. Maybe you can use the generic Node.js atexit handler https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14031763/doing-a-cleanup-action-just-before-node-js-exits

Comment: Also any TCP/IP connections will be automatically terminated when the underlying process dies by the operating system.