# handle 'SIGTERM' signal on AWS Batch Job using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-batch, sigterm

I'm trying to capture this 'SIGTERM' signal that AWS sends just before revoking a SPOT instance or when the job timed out.

Using the function below, I can't see the log, it seems that this function doesn't even execute.

```
process.on('SIGTERM', () => console.log('test SIGNTERM'))
```

the following error appears in the logs:

```
npm ERR! path /
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! signal SIGTERM
npm ERR! command sh -c -- NODE_ENV=dev npx babel-node --presets @babel/preset-env src/functions/entries.js 
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! /root/.npm/_logs/2023-09-27T17_54_18_152Z-debug-0.log
```

Anyone already face it?

My code:

```
process.on('SIGTERM', () => {
  Logger.info('Application received SIGTERM signal');
  process.exit(0);
}

const executeJob = async () => {  
    await sleep(40 * 60 * 1000);
}

executeJob();
```

I made it just for a test, i put a 5 minutes timeout on Job and insert that sleep to get timeout inside AWS Batch Job. That log inside process.on didnt appears.

Comment: Did the existing posts help https://stackoverflow.com/a/14032965/1643558

Comment: I saw, but my problem is just inside aws job. Locally it works.  : /

Comment: You wont get a quick resolution but maybe report it to the free tier support on aws along with instructions and a minimal example of code? maybe they can fix it in a few months