# ws.onclose event does not get called on nodejs exit

Tags: node.js, websocket

i use **web sockets** and the `onclose` method does not get triggert when the server is down.
i tried to close the ws connections manually with `progress.exit` but it seems this only gets triggert on a clean exit.

is their a way to catch a stopped nodejs app and execute code before the stop?
it should trigger on `ctr`+`c` and any other crash/exit.

basicly i want to tell the client when the connection is not alive anymore **before he is trying to do something**, since `onclose` does not handel every case, what can i do to check the connection?

the only solution i came up with is to ping the server from time to time.

Comment: It is normal, although not always wanted, to have a "cleanup limit". Otherwise the server might get stuck in an endless cleanup loop. Hence, you should expect the server's `onclose` method to not always be called.  As for process exit cleanup, consider using the `process.on('exit', function() {});` as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8510008/express-js-shutdown-hook).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since this is not possible i started sending pings as a workarround:

```
var pingAnswer = true;
pingInterval = setInterval(function(){
  if(pingAnswer){
    ws.send(JSON.stringify({type:'ping'})); //on the serverside i just send a ping back everytime i recive one.
    pingAnswer = false;
  }else{
     clearInterval(pingInterval);
    //reload page or something
  }
},1000);
ws.onMessage(function(e){
  m = JSON.parse(e.data);
  switch(m.type){
  ....
  case 'ping':
     pingAnswer=true;
  return; 
  }
}

);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide a snippet showing how you're defining your `on('close',...)` handler, but it's possible that you're defining the handler incorrectly.

At the time of this writing, the documentation for [websocket.onclose](https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/master/doc/ws.md#websocketonclose) led me to first implement the handler as `ws_connection.onclose( () => {...});`, but I've found the proper way to be `ws_connection.on('close', () => {...} );`

Maybe the style used in the ws documentation is some kind of idiom I'm unfamiliar with.

I've tested this with node 6.2.1 and ws 1.1.1. The `on.('close',...)` callback is triggered on either side (server/client) when the corresponding side is shutdown via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> or crashes for whatever reason (for example, for testing, `JSON.parse("fail");` or `throw new Error('');`).