# nodejs exit issue for express routing

Tags: node.js, express, pm2

When developing an API using nodeJS and express, 2 js file involved as below

When I pm2 start main.js, doSth() in api.js works as I expected, however, when I pm2 stop main.js,
cleanSth() not working, anyone can advise how can I achieved my expected result (**cleanSth when I pm2 stop**)?

api.js

> const express = require('express')
>
> doSth()
>
> const routes = (app) => {  ...  ... }
>
> process.on('beforeExit', cleanSth()})
>
> module.exports = routes

main.js

> const express = require('express') const app = express()
>
> const a = require('./api.js') a(app)

Answer (score 0):

As stated in docs https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_beforeexit

> The 'beforeExit' event is not emitted for conditions causing explicit termination, such as calling process.exit() or uncaught exceptions.

So if you only do some synchronous work in `cleanSth` then use `exit` event instead of `beforeExit`

Or you may want to have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64028857/3284355

Comment: The problem is that 'pm2 stop main.js' / 'pm2 restart main.js' do not trigger the 'beforeExit' or 'exit' event