# When to close Database with node-sqlite3 and express?

Tags: node.js, express, sqlite, node-sqlite3

My problem is to figure out when to close a database connection from an expressjs backend to a sqlite database.

What I basically want to achieve is a database connection which is open during the whole server uptime and is closed on server shutdown.

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();

var db = new sqlite3.Database(data/Test.db);

//use db as needed 

var server = app.listen(8081, function () {
    var host = server.address().address
    var port = server.address().port
    console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
});

//on shutdown db.close();
```

I had a look at these threats:

[Stack overflow: process.on('exit', callback)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8510008/express-js-shutdown-hook)

[Github issue: App has no app.close()](https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/1366)

But the suggested solutions wouldn't work for me if I kill me express server with `ctrl+c`.

So what would be a 'best practice' on how to handle an open database connection on server shutdown?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`SIGINT` is the signal you're looking for; most terminals send a `SIGINT` on `Ctrl+C`.

You could try something like this -

```
process.on('SIGINT', () => {
    db.close();
    server.close();
});
```

Comment: That worked for me. I was looking at 'SIGTERM', because I thought this would be send anyways.

Comment: @Link1510 I'd recommend going over the standard signals here - https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#event_exit_